# How to debug "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string" error in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, mysqli

I am working on my academic project, and I am stuck in my search feature, the query that I am trying to run is running smoothly in the MySQL server, but when I try to run it on the application, it is giving me the error like this:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in..........

The code snippets are as follows:

Database connection:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define("DBNAME","foodfood");
global $con;
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "passport";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

The query that is causing error:

```
function find_food ($keysearch, $con) {
        $find_query = "SELECT `vendor`.`v_id`,`vendor`.`v_name`,`vendor`.`v_img`,`contacts`.`cont_addr`,`contacts`.`cont_phn`,`fooditem`.`item_name`,`fooditem`.`fi_price`,`fooditem`.`fc_desc` FROM vendor
LEFT JOIN ".DBNAME.".`contacts` ON `vendor`.`cont_id` = `contacts`.`cont_id` 
LEFT JOIN ".DBNAME.".`fooditem` ON `vendor`.`v_id` = `fooditem`.`v_id`  WHERE `vendor`.`v_name` LIKE '%".$keysearch."%' OR `fooditem`.`item_name` LIKE '%".$keysearch."%';";

//run query
$fill_food = mysqli_query($con, $find_query);
}
```

Now, when I run this code, by inputting the search variable $keysearch (The variables are filtered for any possible injection attacks). I get an error on the line that is:

```
LEFT JOIN ".DBNAME.".`fooditem` ON `vendor`.`v_id` = `fooditem`.`v_id`  WHERE `vendor`.`v_name` LIKE '%".$keysearch."%' OR `fooditem`.`item_name` LIKE '%".$keysearch."%';";
```

UPDATE: I debugged the code and came up with some more information.
I did a var_dump of the variables from the search page from where the $keyword is being picked up. Everything seems fine and i get the entered search string in the var_dump. now this gets interesting when this keyword gets parsed in the next file where i have entered the SQL statement. 
I have the output of the var_dump of this same keyword and i can now see the mysqli object as follows:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: f373ea5dd5538761406a8022a4b8a374418b240e $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.6.21" ["server_version"]=> int(50621) ["stat"]=> string(130) "Uptime: 550 Threads: 1 Questions: 5 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 70 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 63 Queries per second avg: 0.009" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(4) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

now when i put the sql query in the search page itself, i dont get the error specified. but i now get the sql query ready to execute as follows:

```
string(413) "SELECT `vendor`.`v_id`,`vendor`.`v_name`,`vendor`.`v_img`,`contacts`.`cont_addr`,`contacts`.`cont_phn`,`fooditem`.`item_name`,`fooditem`.`fi_price`,`fooditem`.`fc_desc` FROM vendor LEFT JOIN stfood.`contacts` ON `vendor`.`cont_id` = `contacts`.`cont_id` LEFT JOIN stfood.`fooditem` ON `vendor`.`v_id` = `fooditem`.`v_id` WHERE stfood.`vendor`.`v_name` LIKE '%vend%' OR stfood`fooditem`.`item_name` LIKE '%vend%';"
```

now, if i take this query and stick it in mysql server as a query, the query fails, and if i remove the double quotes ("") and then run the query, it successfully runs.
now i have similar statements in other functions and they run properly, but not this one.
Can anyone guide me on where i am making a mistake?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error usually presents itself when you mix `mysqli_` with `mysql_` - Can you do a search for `mysql_` and convert them to `mysqli_`

Comment: searched the mysql_ there is no result in the whole of my document.

Comment: Previous answer was actually incorrect, sorry!

Comment: can anyone please guide me on whats the mistake i am making? i am totally clueless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

finally, i did it... 
the sql queries with lots of foreign keys were causing issues, i made some changes in the script.
* put the search terms and SQL queries on the same page. 
* small changes in the SQL queries.
* used mysqli_num_rows on the mysqli_result object, stored the results in variables and echoed on to the tables. Phew........